# What CSS rule is causing my absolute positioned item from being hidden

Tags: html, css

I have a pretty simple HTML structure and what I'm attempting to achieve is to get the absolute positioned `div.outside` to move beyond the containing `div.content` which is relative positioned. For my case, the `div.outside` *must* be a child of `div.content`. I want to know, what CSS rule is causing this to be hidden?

My assumption is that since the `parent` has an `overflow-x: scroll` then the combination of `overflow-y: visible` (automatically set by the browser?) is not possible? If that's the case, is there any possible way to achieve this with my given constraints?

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="content">

    <div class="outside"></div>

     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. 
     At maiores quo minima officia totam suscipit deleniti 
     perferendis fugiat, hic necessitatibus sit sapiente 
     aperiam, enim voluptatum, unde labore iste ea iusto!

  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.parent {
  width: 250px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.content {
  width: 500px;
  position: relative;
}

.outside {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: red;
  top: -10px;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

**Fiddle**
https://jsfiddle.net/pz7gkyyz/

** Edit **

To give a little more context to my problem, I have a table that scrolls on the horizontal axis because there are many columns (however only the table scrolls and not the whole screen). The column header can be hovered over and a tooltip should be shown. I use the header as the relative point and want to offset the tooltip upwards where it is currently being cut off/hidden.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in your CSS. `.outside` is an empty div. Move text content inside `.outside`

```css
.parent {
  width: 250px;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.content {
  width: 500px;
  background:red;
  position: relative;
}

.outside {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: red;
  top: 10px;
  overflow:hidden;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="outside">
    </div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. At maiores quo minima officia totam suscipit deleniti perferendis fugiat, hic necessitatibus sit sapiente aperiam, enim voluptatum, unde labore iste ea iusto!
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hmm. Tried running this as a fiddle and nothing seemed to appear on the screen. Also, I cannot put the text content inside of the `div.outside`. They are separate entities.

Answer (score 0):

top : -10 is causing this problem, if you remove it you will be able to see it.

```
.outside {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: red;
  top: -10px; // Remove this
  z-index: 999;
}
```

Comment: Yeah I need that. It cannot be changed. Think of a tooltip that is above where you hover.